# Rails seems to be creating objects in wrong time zone for created_at, updated_at values

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I just created a new object using a form and its updated_at and created_at values are

```
created_at: "2013-04-25 03:22:19", updated_at: "2013-04-25 03:22:19",
```

However that is ~7 hours ahead of where I am (PST).

```
Time.now.to_s
 => "2013-04-24 20:23:12 -0700"
```

How can I make sure the time zone is consistent with wherever a user is creating it from?

Comment: Did you set the `config.time_zone` setting?

Comment: Check out `use_zone` [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html#method-c-use_zone) --- If you haven't set the timezone in your config/application.rb file, run `rake time:zones:all` for a list of valid timezones you can set it to.

Comment: Hint: check for config.time_zone comment in config/application.rb

Comment: It is good practice to always store data in UTC, and it sounds like your application is already doing so. If you wish to display a time to your user in his own time zone, store his time zone and handle the conversion in the presentation layer.

Comment: If I set the time_zone to my own, it won't be customized for each user, correct? I'm not sure how to go about what mchail suggested.

Comment: according to @mchail 's idea: 
`time_zone = ActiveSupport::TimeZone.new(time_zone_in_which_you_want_to_convert_to)
current_time = (time_zone == nil ? Time.now : Time.now.in_time_zone(time_zone))`
Thanks.

Answer (score 16):

Your `created_at` and `updated_at` values are written from your server to the database, so they will always be in your server's or application's time zone. By the time the server processes the form data and saves to your database, it has no knowledge of the browser's time zone.

You can set a Rails time zone using `config.time_zone`, as @lulalala suggested.

It sounds like you're interested in displaying times to your users in their native time zones. You have two options for this:

- Ask your user for a time zone on signup (or assign a default one and allow users to edit it)
- Detect time zone using javascript and report back to your server (http://josephscott.org/archives/2009/08/detecting-client-side-time-zone-offset-via-javascript/) - not guaranteed to be correct

Once you have the time zone saved as a user attribute, you can display your times to your users like this:

```
Model.created_at.in_time_zone(@current_user.time_zone)
```

Answer (score 3):

I check `irb` timezone with the command `> Time.now.to_s` and the time was correct, but the app save it wrong by 3 hours. So..

The solution for me was add `config.time_zone = "Santiago"` to `config/environments/development.rb`file. The time zone list is [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html), and my entry was

```
"Santiago" => "America/Santiago"
```

Comment: If you run your application just for one time zone you can also set it for all environments in `application.rb` like `config.time_zone = 'Europe/Berlin'`.